# What are those complex file links used by Instagram and how do I download them using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Example link:
`https://instagram.fpoz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/300583237_1683190978729709_1235944660872477404_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fpoz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=cWI63wAo6REAX-1lE4e&tn=XhoWrBHwHV39KLOw&edm=ALQROFkBAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=MjkxMTE4OTUxMDk4Njg5NDkxNg%3D%3D.2-ccb7-5&oh=00_AfCpwQ-MdbBz6DesKgcVL3E-heiJj03BqqY7ZrpfUFdz1w&oe=63646DA2&_nc_sid=30a2ef`

It's a link I grabbed by inspecting the page. When I enter it, it shows me the image and let's me rightclick->save as..., but if try to download it with:

```
 function download(filename, url) {
  let element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(url));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

I get a broken 1kb file. Is it possible to somehow download such a link? What are those things after the question mark `.jpg?stp=dst` for? If I remove them it breaks it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(url));
> ```

Your setting the value of the `href` attribute to a data: URI.

The value of that `data:` URI is a **text file** containing a URL. It isn't the contents of the resource the URL locates.

It's 1k because a URL is a short bit of text. It's broken because you're trying to open the downloaded text file with an image viewing or editing program (and it isn't an image).

If you want to get that then you'll need to make an Ajax request to it, read the response (and probably be blocked at that point due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)), then generate a Base64 string from the result and generate the right header for the `data:` URL from that.

---

> What are those things after the question mark .jpg?stp=dst for?

That is a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

It is processed by Instagram's servers and I doubt the specifics of the various parameters are publicly documented.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Does "(and probably be blocked at that point due to the same origin policy)" imply that it's probably pointless to even try, or are your instructions an actual recipe for making it work?

Comment: Instagram are highly unlikely to grant permission via CORS, so you would need a server side work around and that might run into authentication issues. It might be possible. There are lots of likely barriers to overcome.